# Javascript doesn't update document in browser

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a data.json in my server directory. I am using the following code from w3school to show the data in the browser. [W3school Snippet Link](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_callback)

```
<button type="button" onclick="loadDoc()">Change Content</button>
<script>
function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;

    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "/static/data.json", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
</script>
</html>
```

When i click the button, I am able to see the **data.json** in my webpage. But when i change the **data.json** and click the button again (without refreshing the page), the updated data isn't shown in the browser.

Am i missing something here?

Comment: File`data.json` is getting cached, you need cache buster. You can try `"/static/data.json?v=1.0"`

Comment: You are loading the same file again and again. Then obviously same content will be loaded.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy, _But when i change the data.json and click the button again_

Comment: @Satpal adding ?v=1.0 at the end doesn't work. But yeah, you are right it's because .js file is caching the file in memory.

Comment: @SeasonalShot The `1.0` has to change each time, so it should be a randomly generated string. Or you need to configure the server to send cache control headers to prevent or reduce caching.

Comment: If you're not needing to conform to any strict *RESTful* api / rules, you could instead just use `POST` instead of `GET` as the response won't be cached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   xhttp.open("GET", "/static/data.json?something=RANDOMGUID", true);
```

Comment: A little description is always helpful in understanding the issue.

Comment: The issue becomes obvious when you understand the solution.

Comment: What do we do if we get data from 2 different locations? eg "/static/data2.json?

Comment: You do the same thing with each file you don't want to be cached.

Answer (score 1):

Well since you are using XMLHttpRequest, you need to make sure that every request is kind of unique, you can do something like:

```
var uniqueId = (new Date()).getTime()

xhttp.open("GET", "/static/data.json?debug=" + uniqueId, true);
```

If you were using jQuery ajax (http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), you just have to pass `cache=false`, like this:

```
$.ajax({
  cache: false,
  //other options...
});
```